# AWS' EMR vs EC2 pricing confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, emr

https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/
Can someone explain why the price for EMR and EC2 differs so much, we are considering whether build our spark cluster on EMR or using Clourdera on EC2. Did I miss anything obvious? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is EMR?

> Amazon EMR provides a managed Hadoop framework that makes it easy,
>   fast, and cost-effective to process vast amounts of data across
>   dynamically scalable Amazon EC2 instances.

What is [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)?

> Amazon EC2’s simple web service interface allows you to obtain and
>   configure capacity with minimal friction. It provides you with
>   complete control of your computing resources and lets you run on
>   Amazon’s proven computing environment.

Now, what is [EMR pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/)?

EMR pricing is essentially the price you pay for "Cluster Management" related computing.

In a big data setup, cluster computing is not enough, you need "node computing" too, that is where [EC2 and it's pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) comes into picture.

As explained in [EMR Pricing documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/emr/pricing/), you will be charged for both EMR computing & EC2 computing when you use EMR.

> The Amazon EMR price is in addition to the Amazon EC2 price (the price
>   for the underlying servers). There are a variety of Amazon EC2 pricing
>   options you can choose from, including On-Demand (shown below), 1 year
>   & 3 year Reserved Instances, and Spot instances.

Why the pricing different?

It depends on what type of service & hardware being used and ultimately only AWS team can answer.